# Spring JPA : create Sort and Direction based on a list of Strings

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

Unfortunately, I can't modify the controller to accept a Pageable instance. Instead, I only have `Integer page`, `Integer pageSize` and `List<String> sort` parameters. The URL query parameters for the `sort` are passed in as follows:

`sort=name,asc&sort=modificationDate,asc&sort=creationDate,asc...`

So, the `List<String> sort` in the controller will contain a list of values:

```
"name", "asc", "modificationDate", "asc", "creationDate", "asc"...
```

How is it possible to instantiate a `Pageable` instance based on the above values? I tried to look at the source code but found nothing to give an idea.
The `org.springframework.data.domain.PageRequest` has some methods like these:

```
    public static PageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort sort) {
        return new PageRequest(page, size, sort);
    }

    public static PageRequest of(int page, int size, Sort.Direction direction, String... properties) {
        return of(page, size, Sort.by(direction, properties));
    }
```

but none of them seems to suit the case.
Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert `List<String>` to `Sort` object first:

```java
public Sort convertToSort(List<String> sortFields) {
    List<Sort.Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String field : sortFields) {
        String[] propertyAndDirection = field.split(",");
        String property = propertyAndDirection[0];
        Sort.Direction direction = Sort.DEFAULT_DIRECTION;
        if(propertyAndDirection.length > 1) {
            String directionString = propertyAndDirection[1];
            direction = Sort.Direction.fromOptionalString(directionString)
                    .orElse(Sort.DEFAULT_DIRECTION);
        }
        Sort.Order order = new Sort.Order(direction, property);
        orders.add(order);
    }
    return Sort.by(orders);
}
```

Then in your controller you can make use of `PageRequest`

```java
@GetMapping("/sort")
public void sortExample(@RequestParam(required = false) List<String> sort,
                    @RequestParam(required = false) Integer page,
                    @RequestParam(required = false) Integer pageSize) {
    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page, pageSize, convertToSort(sort));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I don't think it can work because as I mentioned, the `List<String> sort` looks like `"name", "asc", "modificationDate", "asc", "creationDate", "asc"`, - so there is no `,` to split on, - it is just a List of `column`, `direction` values.

Comment: According to the example given in the question, it does work. When you pass `sort=name,asc&sort=modificationDate,asc&sort=creationDate,asc`(the same as you gave in the example) to controller `List<String> sort` will have three string values: `name,asc` `modificationDate,asc` `creationDate,asc`.

Comment: Yeah, my bad, just checked it when debugging, thanks a lot !